# Too much gas consumption

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm programming my first Eth Contract, I'm facing a problem, the gas consumption ( estimated ) of the `buy` method is going really to high ( Quickly > N million gas before getting the "Maximum gas allowance exceeded" error. )

To be quick, the idea is the following:

- There is a map ( 2D map ) with multiple zones that you can own ( called units here, this is why I maintain a "unitsToState" obvious mapping ).
- You can purchase multiple adjacent zones at once, so a "Block" is created.
- So when you purchase a new Block the contract must check if all the units inside are empty ( unitsToState[x] == 0 ). When the block is purchased, these states are set to 1.

I don't explain too much details here, because I guess the problem is mainly "Solidity" bad algorithm programming from me.

This method can be executed with arround 500k gas for fromX, fromY, toX, toY that represent a small zone, but when those are far from each other, I got the "Maximum gas allowance exceeded" error during my gas estimation .. So really I guess there is a problem ..

```
    ...

    struct Block {
        address owner;
        uint fromX;
        uint fromY;
        uint toX;
        uint toY;
        string imageUrl;
        string redirectUrl;
        string text;
        bool removed;
    }   
    
    uint size = 100;
    mapping (uint => uint) unitsToState;
    Block[] public blocks;
    uint public areaPrice;
    uint public areaPerUnit;

    ...


    function buy(uint fromX, uint fromY, uint toX, uint toY, string imageUrl, string redirectUrl, string text) payable public {
        require(fromX >= 0);
        require(fromY >= 0);
        require(fromX <= toX);
        require(fromY <= toY);
        require(toX < size);
        require(toY < size);
        
        // Here do check of collisions.
        for (uint i = fromX; i <= toX; i++) {
            for (uint j = fromY; j <= toY; j++) {
                require(getUnitsToState(i*size*size + j) == 0);
            }    
        }
        
        uint width = toX - fromX + 1;
        uint height = toY - fromY + 1;
        uint areaCount = width * height * areaPerUnit;
        uint price = areaCount * areaPrice;
        require(msg.value >= price);
        
        Block memory b = Block(
           msg.sender,
           fromX,
           fromY,
           toX,
           toY,
           imageUrl,
           redirectUrl,
           text,
           false
        );
        blocks.push(b);
        
        // Registrer units states.
        for (i = fromX; i <= toX; i++) {
            for (j = fromY; j <= toY; j++) {
                unitsToState[i*size*size + j] = 1;
            }    
        }
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Large loops, especially with nested loops, are dangerous in Solidity. You have to be careful what logic you're executing on each iteration.

In your case, it's the second loop where you're setting the `unitsToState` flag that is causing the huge spike in gas usage. Every call to store non-zero data costs 20,000 gas (5,000 for zero). You're incurring that cost every iteration of your loop.

It looks like you have everything you need to do your collision check inside the `Block` struct. Can you just use that?

```
for (uint8 i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  Block storage bTest = blocks[i];

  bool xIntersect = int(fromX) - int(bTest.toX) <= 0 && int(toX) - int(bTest.fromX) >= 0;
  bool yIntersect = int(fromY) - int(bTest.toY) <= 0 && int(toY) - int(bTest.fromY) >= 0;

  require (!(xIntersect && yIntersect));
}
```

See [Appendix G of the yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) for gas costs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But the thing is that the block area can go up to a length equals to 10,000 ... will it not cost more than the actual code in the long term ? The actual logic is a lot gas consumming but constant gas consumming. Your point ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. The larger the block size, the more efficient this approach should be. Your version searches until it finds a unit that collides. What I posted checks at the block level to see if the x and y ranges overlap what is being requested. In any case, as mentioned in my original comment, the biggest hit in your gas usage is `unitsToState[i*size*size + j] = 1;` in the loop. Feel free to test the version I posted with 10,000 1x1 blocks purchased (worst case), and see if it performs.

Comment: Yep, I will try that and update my cost after. One question, why did you put the keyword "storage" when declaring "Block storage bTest" ?

Comment: It's not needed. Local variables of type struct are storage anyway. I just typed it out of habit.